# Why does the impl of shared_ptr ref count hold a pointer to the actual pointed type?

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-ptr

This was motivated by an interview question:

```cpp
shared_ptr<void> p(new Foo());
```

Will the destructor of `Foo` get called once `p` goes out of scope?

It turns out it does, I had to look at the implementation of `shared_ptr` in GCC <sup>1</sup>, and find out that apparently the control block holds a pointer to the actual type (`Foo`) and a pointer to the destructor that gets invoked when the ref count reaches 0.

<sup>1</sup>: Sorry I am on my phone I cannot copy the link to the impl.

But I am still wondering: why? Why is it needed? Is there anything I am missing from the standard?

On the other hand, the line above doesn't compile with `unique_ptr` because obviously there's no ref count in that case.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71821115/incomplete-types-with-shared-ptr-and-unique-ptr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `std::shared_ptr<T>` instance itself must keep track of the pointer to return when `.get()` is called. This is always of type `T*`, except when `T` is an array, in which case it is of type `std::remove_extent_t<T>*` (for example, `std::shared_ptr<int[]>::get()` returns `int*`).

Also, when a `std::shared_ptr<T>` is destroyed, it has to check whether it is the last `std::shared_ptr` instance referring to its control block. If so, it must execute the deleter. In order for this to work, the control block must keep track of the pointer to pass to the deleter. It is *not necessarily* of the type `T*` or `std::remove_extent_t<T>*`.

The reason why these are not the same is that, for example, code like the following should work:

```
struct S {
    int member;
    int other_member;
    ~S();
};
void foo(std::shared_ptr<int>);
int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<S> sp = std::make_shared<S>();
    std::shared_ptr<int> ip(sp, &sp->member);
    foo(std::move(ip));
}
```

Here, `sp` owns an object of type `S` and also points to the same object. The function `foo` takes a `std::shared_ptr<int>` because it is part of some API that needs an `int` object that will remain alive for as long as the API isn't done with it (but the caller can also keep it alive for longer, if they want). The `foo` API doesn't care whether the `int` that you give it is part of some larger object; it just cares that the `int` will not be destroyed while it is holding on to it. So, we can create a `std::shared_ptr<int>` named `ip`, which points to `sp->member`, and pass that to `foo`. Now, this `int` object can only survive as long as the enclosing `S` object is alive. It follows that `ip` must, as long as it is alive, keep the *entire* `S` object alive. We could now call `sp.reset()` but the `S` object must remain alive, since there is still a `shared_ptr` referring to it. Finally, when `ip` is destroyed, it must destroy the *entire* `S` object, not just the `int` that it, itself, points to. Thus, it is not enough for the `std::shared_ptr<int>` instance `ip` to store a `int*` (which will be returned when `.get()` is called); the control block that it points to also has to store the `S*` to pass to the deleter.

For the same reason, your code will call the `Foo` destructor even though it is a `std::shared_ptr<void>` that is carrying out the destruction.

You asked: "Is there anything I am missing from the standard?" By this I assume you are asking whether the standard requires this behaviour and if so, where in the standard is it specified? The answer is yes. The standard specifies that a `std::shared_ptr<T>` *stores* a pointer and may also *own* a pointer; these two pointers need not be the same. In particular, [[util.smartptr.shared.const]/14](http://eel.is/c++draft/util.smartptr.shared.const#14) describes constructors that "[construct] a `shared_ptr` instance that *stores* `p` and *shares ownership with* the initial value of `r`" (emphasis mine). The `shared_ptr` instance thus created may own a pointer that is different from the one it stores. However, when it is destroyed, [[util.smartptr.shared.dest]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/util.smartptr.shared.dest#1) applies: if this is the last instance, the *owned* pointer is deleted (not the *stored* one).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that for this code the answer is trivial:

```
shared_ptr<Foo> p(new Foo());
```

Every call to `new` must be balanced by a call to `delete`. Every constructed object must be destructed too. So if

```
shared_ptr<void> p(new Foo());
```

would not call ~Foo() that would be rather surprising and would cause resource leaks, dangling pointers or any number of UB caused by the destructor not being called.

For me the bigger question is: Why does that compile at all? The `shared_ptr` has the wrong type so it shouldn't be able to call the right destructor and that should not compile (like `unique_ptr` fails).

The reason for that is this little bit of genius I believe:

```
template< class Y > shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r, element_type* ptr ) noexcept;
template< class Y > shared_ptr( shared_ptr<Y>&& r, element_type* ptr ) noexcept;
```

You can create a shared pointer pointing at a member of a larger object, which will keep the larger object alive as long as the pointer to the member exists.

For this feature to work the `shared_ptr` and the control block of the `shared_ptr` both have a pointer and they can have different types. The control block always points to the object while the `shared_ptr` points to the member. When you normaly create a `shared_ptr` they happen to be the same type and point to the same address. But apparently that isn't always the case.

This also allows making a `shared_ptr<void>` with the control block pointing at a `Foo`. Here both point to the same address but have different type. The control block know the type of the original object and what destructor to call in the end.

How does that work? The `shared_ptr` and control block can have different types of pointers and that allows for these copy constructors:

```
template< class Y > shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r ) noexcept;
template< class Y > shared_ptr( shared_ptr<Y>&& r ) noexcept;
```

As long as `Y*` is convertible / compatible with `T*` you can change the type of the `shared_ptr` during copy construction. The given code actually turns into this:

```
shared_ptr<void> p(shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo()));
```

It creates a temporary `shared_ptr<Foo>` with the control block having a `Foo*` and then `p` reuses the same control block.

Answer (score 0):

[std::shared_ptr::shared_ptr - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)

> |  |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | `constexpr shared_ptr() noexcept;` | (1) |
> | `constexpr shared_ptr( std::nullptr_t ) noexcept;` | (2) |
> | `template< class Y > explicit shared_ptr( Y* ptr );` | (3) |
> | ..... | ... |
>
> ....
>
> 3-7) Constructs a `shared_ptr` with `ptr` as the pointer to the managed object.
>
> |  |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | For *(3-4,6)*, `Y*` must be convertible to `T*`. | (until C++17) |
> | If `T` is an array type `U[N]`, *(3-4,6)* do not participate in overload resolution if `Y(*)[N]` is not convertible to `T*`. If `T` is an array type `U[]`, *(3-4,6)* do not participate in overload resolution if `Y(*)[]` is not convertible to `T*`. Otherwise, *(3-4,6)* do not participate in overload resolution if `Y*` is not convertible to `T*`. | (since C++17) |
>
> Additionally:
>
> 3. Uses the **[delete-expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete)** delete ptr if `T` is not an array type; `delete[]` ptr if `T` is an array type *(since C++17)* as the deleter. `Y` must be a complete type. The delete expression must be well-formed, have well-defined behavior and not throw any exceptions. This constructor additionally does not participate in overload resolution if the delete expression is not well-formed. (since C++17)

So basically third form is used.

Also data holding reference counters (strong and weak) holds also information about  destructor of the object. This `(3)` form of constructor fetches this information.

Note that `std::unique_ptr` by default do not hold such information and so it will fail in this scenario (fails to compile).