# Why unique_ptr requires complete type in constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, unique-ptr, incomplete-type

From [Is std::unique_ptr required to know the full definition of T?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012157/is-stdunique-ptrt-required-to-know-the-full-definition-of-t), I know that if a class `A` has a member `unique_ptr<T>`, then `T` shall be a complete type in destructor `~A()`. However, I came across a situation that the constructor `A()` also requires complete type of `T`, see code below:

```cpp
// a.h -------------------------------
#pragma once
#include <memory>
struct B;
struct A {
  A(); // <---
  ~A();
  std::unique_ptr<B> ptr;
};

// a.cpp -------------------------------
#include "a.h"
struct B {};
A::A() = default; // <---
A::~A() = default;

// main.cpp -------------------------------
#include "a.h"
int main() {A a;}
```

If the definition of constructor `A::A()` is moved to the header `a.h`, the compiler will complain `error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘B’`. Why is this happening? Is there any reference material about this?

BTW, I'm using gcc-7.5.0 on Ubuntu 18.04, with c++17 enabled.

---

Edit for @463035818_is_not_a_number in the comments. The complete error message is:

```bash
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/t.dir/main.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/t.dir/main.cpp.o 
/usr/bin/c++   -g -fdiagnostics-color=always -std=gnu++1z -MD -MT CMakeFiles/t.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/t.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/t.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/user/Tests/UniquePtrTest/main.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/memory:80:0,
                 from /home/user/Tests/UniquePtrTest/a.h:2,
                 from /home/user/Tests/UniquePtrTest/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::default_delete<_Tp>::operator()(_Tp*) const [with _Tp = B]’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:263:17:   required from ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::~unique_ptr() [with _Tp = B; _Dp = std::default_delete<B>]’
/home/user/Tests/UniquePtrTest/a.h:5:3:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:76:22: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘B’
  static_assert(sizeof(_Tp)>0,
                      ^
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: The constructor needs to know how to destruct all the fields, in case at any moment during the construction an exception is thrown.

Comment: @MatteoItalia seems like your explanation should apply to using the same A() = default in the class declaration (in the h file). But the compiler issues no error if you do it like that.

Comment: @wohlstad - Compile as C++20, then you won't be dealing with silly aggregate.

Comment: btw `#include` is basically just replacing text, hence it should be possible to reproduce it with code in a single file. Would make it simpler to reproduce for others

Comment: @StoryTeller-Unslander Monica I don't follow. I was referring to defining the `A` ctor as `=default`. This works in the class declaration (`A() = default;`) but not outside as `A::A() = default;`. In both cases I removed the line `struct B {};`.

Comment: @wohlstad - What's to follow in "compile as C++20"?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica you mentioned _"silly aggregate"_. I didn't understand how it is related. And BTW - I am compiling as C++20.

Comment: @wohlstad - Interesting. `struct A { A() = default; };` is an aggregate pre c++20, and not later. That *would* affect there not actually being a c'tor body to error out on. I imagine your testing has something else in the mix.

Comment: Now I understand your mention of _aggregate_. However - my test is minimal - similar to the OP's code, and I get the same behavior when I compile both as C++17 and as C++20. I am using VS2022, version 17.2.5.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Sorry, I cannot reproduce it with code in a single file. Could you provide an example?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71821115/incomplete-types-with-shared-ptr-and-unique-ptr

Comment: I also didnt manage to reproduce. I admit I don't understand, must have something to do with `A a;` being in a different translation unit, I guess if you remove that from `main` the error is also gone

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes, different translation unit matters.

Comment: hm well, then I'd ask you to include the complete error message in the question. It seems like the error is from main, but thats not clear from the question.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I posted this question regarding the issue I menioned above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75409177/difference-between-constructor-definitoins-of-a-class-holding-a-stdunique-ptr.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is that `A::A()` needs to know how to destroy `ptr` in case the constructor throws.

An example:

```
#include <memory>
struct B {};

struct X{
    X(){throw 42;}
};

struct A {
  A() {}
  ~A() {};
  std::unique_ptr<B> ptr;
  X x;
};


int main() {
    A a;
}
```

generates:

```
A::A() [base object constructor]:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 24
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rdi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::unique_ptr<B, std::default_delete<B> >::unique_ptr<std::default_delete<B>, void>()
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        add     rax, 8
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    X::X() [complete object constructor]
        jmp     .L6
        mov     rbx, rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::unique_ptr<B, std::default_delete<B> >::~unique_ptr() [complete object destructor]
        mov     rax, rbx
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    _Unwind_Resume
```

showing the call to `std::unique_ptr<B, std::default_delete<B> >::~unique_ptr()`.

> Is there any reference material about this?

Technically, yes, you can read the Standard which defines which functions/expressions require a complete type.

Practically, not so much, since you have to read the Standard which defines which functions/expressions require a complete type.

Of course [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) is of high quality and actually readable, although I did not find this use case there.

In particular, this issue is mentioned in a note
[20.11.1.3.3 Destructor [unique.ptr.single.dtor]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/unique.ptr.single#dtor)

> [Note 1 : The use of default_delete requires T to be a complete type. — end note]

Comment: Thanks. It seems the problem about my case is that: If `A::A()` is defined in `a.h`, the ctor won't be compiled in `a.o`. Then `main.o` compiles `A::A()` from the header, while `B` is a incomplete type here.

Comment: @VictorBian Yes, exactly because then the definition is inline inside the header with the incomplete `B`. Sorry, should have said that explicitly. Had you had `main` inside `a.cpp`, it would have worked I think.

Answer (score 3):

The error you see is `std::default_deleter` guarding against undefined behaviour for you.

When you instantiate the definition of the constructor `std::unique_ptr<B>::unique_ptr`, the definition of `std::default_delete<B>::operator()` is also instantiated. Within which is an assertion

```
static_assert(sizeof(B) > 0);
```

which checks for incomplete types. This prevents any possible deletion of an incomplete type, which is undefined behaviour. See also [incomplete types with shared_ptr and unique_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71821115/incomplete-types-with-shared-ptr-and-unique-ptr).

But why does moving the definition of `A::A()` to the header cause an error but not if it's in the implementation file?

As it turns out, simply declaring the member `std::unique_ptr<B>` only instantiates the *declaration* of its constructor but not the definition. Therefore if `A::A()` is defined in the implementation file, the definition of `std::default_delete<B>::operator()` is also only instantiated then, by which `B` is a complete type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you and @Quimby together answered my question.